# How to control hololens app with pc?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm newbies for hololens and learning app develop for hololens. I want to have this effect. For example, I click a button in unity editor,then a movie start to play in hololens. May be I can use something like tcp...But I don't know how to start...

Comment: what have you tried so far? are you trying to run code when play is pressed or for the output to be on the hololens screen straight away?

Comment: I want to run some code in hololens at the same time when I click button in pc...

Comment: so what have you tried so far? or do you want someone to do it for you?

Comment: Well, as you said you are beginner then [**Microsoft Mixed Reality Academy  official tut**][1] is very helpful and perfect way to get start with hololens. While regarding your specific video play question, I want to tell you there is no extra ordinary code require to do this task. You just need to keep in mind that Hololense support three new input modality gaze, gesture and voice




  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/academy

Comment: I have already read all Academy tutorial except 240,since I only have one hololens and I want to comunicate from pc to hololens, not hololens to hololens... Do you know any tutorial about that?

Answer (score 0):

Hololens was not thought to work in that way. Hololens is an untethered device, so if you want to interact with a PC, you need to develop it. You can start working with the Sharing Service [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/holograms-240).

Comment: Since I only have one hololens and haven't read about that. I will go to check it. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

"I want to run some code in hololens at the same time when I click button in pc"

A server would solve this problem. You create a simple PC app that manipulates a value on your server (e.g. with a button). You then make a server call from Hololens and fetch the value. The app on the hololens then responds to the fetched value with the wanted code.